# Recenter User Orientation on X and Y axis on with Oculus GO and Unity

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I am working on an Oculus GO App for patients in a doctors chair. They'll be using Oculus GO Headsets while sitting, lying, or something in between. So what I am trying to do is to recenter the HMD orientation when the HMD is mounted. But since the patients position can be seated or lying horizontally, I will need to recenter the rotation on all three axis, or at least X and Y.

Unity provides:

```
UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.Recenter();
```

But that will only recenter the Y Axis.

Oculus Integration provides:

```
OVRManager.display.RecenterPose();
```

But under the hood its just using the Unity InputTracking.Recenter() again.

So how can I recenter my whole scene or the player on y-axis as well? 
If you go to Oculus GO main menue and push the recenter button on your controller, it does exactly what I want. However I can't find a way to do the same thing in my Unity application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Y rotation is pretty safe to change, since the player doesn't have an absolute sense of bearing relative to, say, North. But typically X & Z rotation comes from the inclination of the user's head with respect to gravity, which the player can feel. If your vestibular system says you're looking downward with respect to gravity, but the VR scene says you're looking straight out toward the horizon, this can make it seem like the whole room is slanted, or cause simulation sickness. Are you sure you want to override this inclination information?

Comment: That sure is true @DMGregory! However this is just a Video Player, not something that requires much orientation and such. I want to try rotating the X Axis, since I can't have patients lifting up their heads all the time just to see the Cinema Screen while being operated lol

Comment: Have you considered just rotating the screen to match their head? This will mean less fighting with the Oculus tracking features.

Comment: The skybox is a stereo simulation of a cinema, so right now this would not work out well. I will take it into consideration to change up the whole thing to something more abstract though.

Comment: There's nothing to prevent rotating the skybox too. ;)